# hosting a react web app and a docker laravel app with nginx

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, networking, dns

I have 2 apps I'm trying to host on one machine (Ubuntu 22). The first app is a client side react app that makes api calls to my backend which is a docker compose laravel/nginx/sql. I went into `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/MY.DOMAIN.COM` and added the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm; #index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 81;
        listen [::]:81;
        root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name MY_DOMAIN_NAME.COM www.MY_DOMAIN_NAME.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }       

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

On port 80 is where my react app lives. When someone visits MY.DOMAIN.COM I'm able to serve it without any issues. I'm not sure why putting `server_name MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE;` works there vs the domain name like I did for port 81 `server_name MY_DOMAIN_NAME.COM www.MY_DOMAIN_NAME.com;`. Anyway on port 81 is where my laravel app should live. It's using a docker-compose.yml with this configuration:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    app:
        build:
            args:
                user: admin
                uid: 1000
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: my-laravel
        container_name: my-laravel-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/
#        command: bash -c "php artisan migrate:fresh --seed"
#        depends_on:
#            -   db
#        links:
#            -   db
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - my-laravel

    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.30
        container_name: my-laravel-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        networks:
            - my-laravel

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: my-laravel-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '8081:81'
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - my-laravel

networks:
    my-laravel:
        driver: bridge
```

The react app is trying to make api calls to `const domain = "http://MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE:8081";` and fails with the message `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` This is where I'm not sure what I did wrong.

I have nginx installed, but I'm also using it in the docker image. Is there any conflict there? Do I even need to configure my installed nginx instance to serve the docker image?

Anyway, the funny thing is I had this all setup and working last week, but I decided to add an ssl cert with cert bot which messed everything up and now I'm starting from scratch. The problem is I don't remember how I got it working to being with lol.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You have an nginx container that is running an nginx that listens to 2 ports (backend at 81 and frontend at 80). Then you are exposing 81 as 8081 on your host which means your backend should be accessible via your host only. However you can only access the front-end and can't access the backend. That's the opposite of what I would expect given your configuration. However you are also using a socket to connect nginx to PHP but that will probably not work because sockets are only used to connect locally running services and not across containers.

Comment: @apokryfos I have installed nginx on the pc. I also have it in the docker container. I want to be able to run the backend app in the docker container. Do I need to configure the installed nginx to listen on the same port as the docker container? Do I even need nginx if I'm using it in the container? When I look at the docker compose up output I don't see any GET request even coming in... I'm confused myself... looking for some clarity, thank you.

Comment: No you do not need nginx installed locally if it's in a container. As I mentioned you can't use fastcgi via a socket in this setup you'd need something like `fastcgi_pass app:9000` to forward requests to php files to your app container at the default PHP FPM port (assuming you are using PHP-FPM, if you are not this will not work at all). I suspect the reason why your front-end is working is because you've confused configurations. Your frontend is running on port 80 **in the container** but that port is not mapped on the host.

Comment: @apokryfos Ok, figured it out. I just had to change the port to 80 in the container and everything is working again.